# Python + NGINX + Open Server на Windows 7

Tags: python, django, nginx

Здравствуйте, пожалуйста, подскажите как подключить Python + DJango на NGINX, Open Server, Windows 7?

Знаю, что сервера лучше разворачивать на системах Linux, но пока такой возможности нету, в поисковиках решения не нашла.

Comment: А вам обязательно нужен nginx? Если речь идет о тестировании и написании сайта то можно обойтись и без nginx, как и локальный сайт может отлично существовать без web сервера

Comment: на виндовсе IIS есть, на нём можно разворачивать.

Comment: Проще поставить Linux в VirtualBox или VMWare и там поднимать nginx/django и всё что угодно